# Question regarding maximal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider $M$ is a maximal subgroup of finite group $G$. If $M$ is a maximal subgroup that would imply if $H$ is also a subgroup and $M\leq H\leq G$. Then either $M=H$ or $M=G$. Now If $M$ is a non normal subgroup of $G$ then proof that number of non identity elements present in the conjugates of $M$ is at most $(|M|-1)|G:M|$.

Now my solution is 
$N_{G}(M)=M$ As $N_{G}(M)\geq M$. So number of elements by conjugation on $M$ will be $|G:M|$. Now each subgroup in conjugacy has same order. Then total non identity element will be $(|M|-1)|G:M|$. But it isn't the maximum case. It is the usual number. So where am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do u know the problem I am having

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is your question?

Comment: I mean when the maximum case will reach. I am finding that max case will reach for all groups

Comment: Essentially, I think you are forgetting that some of the conjugates of $M$ may intersect non-trivially, so it is not true in general that the union of the conjugates will have the size you claim.

Comment: Consider for example the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$. It has order $8$, is maximal and non-normal. There are $3$ conjugates, with $7$ non-identity element each, but their union only has $15$ non-identity elements, because they all contain the Klein normal subgroup of $S_4$.